# Zsh Bad Substitution Error When Using Q Modifier

Tags: zsh

I'm running into some difficulty with some code where I'm trying to parse the output and escape file names that need to be submitted in .zsh scripting.  I'm getting the error **${(@q)i}: bad substitution** on the following code:

```
arr=($(suitecloud file:list --folder "/SuiteScripts"))

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
        echo ${(@q)i} >> $name_fix
        suitecloud file:import --paths $name_fix
done
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I need to do to return the proper output?

Comment: That's the error message *bash* would typically output, so it looks like you're trying to have bash (or possibly sh if sh is bash on your system) interpret that code.

Comment: Also, `${arr[@]}` (or `$arr[@]`) only make sense when quoted. When unquoted, you might as well use `for i in $arr` which does the same thing (loop over non-empty elements).

Comment: Also `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data, unless you use `echo -E - $data`. Alternatively: `printf '%s\n' "$date"` (POSIX) or `print -r - "$data"` (like in ksh)

Comment: `arr=($(cmd))` would split the output of `cmd` on `$IFS`. If you want to to store into `$arr` the non-empty lines of the output of `$cmd`, you'd rather use `arr=(${(f)"$(cmd)"})`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Why don't you write all that in an answer? :)